# How to turn off furigana syntax in comment?

Tags: support, comments

I wanted to write:

> You can include *furigana* with the syntax [kanji] {kana}: see my edit.

But it displays [kanji]{kana}, with is not very useful to the OP. I tried single and triple quotes (for code): I get furigana. I tried html comment: it displays. Adding a space works (as above), but only if I want to get the syntax to display wrong.

Comment: [漢字] {ふりがな} ... あれっ、できた？＾＾

Answer (score 3):

Put a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) in between the `[kanji]` and the `{kana}` parts, and it'll show up the way you want.

With zero-width space:

> [kanji]​{kana}

Without zero-width space:

> [kanji]{kana}

You can type `&#8203;` to get a zero-width space in an answer, but in a comment you'll probably have to copy-and-paste it from somewhere (like Wikipedia).

Comment: [kanji]​{kana} ...あっ、できた ＾＾

Answer (score 0):

Put a space or [hair space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+200A) between `[漢字]` and `{ふりがな}`.

> [漢字] {ふりがな}

(＾＾)v

---

ゼロ幅スペースが挟まったものを[コメント](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/how-to-turn-off-furigana-syntax-in-comment/1940#comment4432_1941)からコピーして貼ると：

[kanji]​{kana}

あ、やっぱりコピペするとダメなのね・・

Comment: But if the OP were to copy and paste, it would not work.

Comment: ですよね...... (T_T)

Comment: @MathieuBouville I guess you can say not to copy-and-paste in your comment.